# Show on Lock Screen push notification settings?

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

To get push notifications settings for an app I use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].currentUserNotificationSettings
```

and then I check for the types of `UIUserNotificationSettings`. There are only 4 types `None`, `Badge`, `Sound`, `Alert`. If I use an app with settings like this:

[image]

I get that `Sound`, `Badge`, `Alert` is disabled and `None` is enabled. Why is `None` enabled if I still have “Show on Lock Screen” switch to ON? I am confused, is the “Show on Lock Screen” treated somehow different? From my understanding the app should still be able to receive push messages. Is there any way to find out “Show on Lock Screen” switch value for push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

The API gives you access to the alert style when unlocked.

Given the fact that you still have the option `Allow Notifications` turned on, your app will still receive push notifications. So, by putting a `breakpoint` in code you'll see it being executed when you receive a push notification.

The `currentUserNotificationSettings` will tell you which type of alert style will be used for displaying when the phone is unlocked: `None` is a viable option and, along with `Badge App Icon` disabled your app can receive Push Notifications without showing any type of Banner, Alert, or Badge.

`Show on Lock Screen` can be seen as a way for the user to customize which notifications are and aren't presented, and in which way, in its phone. I don't think there's an API that will tell you whether or not that option is enabled.

I've just tested `Messages.app` with the exact same configuration you presented  and by sending messages to myself there was no Badge, no Banner, no Alert but if I quickly lock the screen the phone wakes up with a notification in the Lock Screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I leave only Sound enabled, I won’t receive None. So it is strange that “Show on Lock Screen” is treated completely different. Does it mean that there is no way to know that push notifications were disabled for the app?